# URL Rewrite from base (without prefix) .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am developing a short link website for a brand, and I need to have the links look like this:

```
http://demo-name.com/[shortvalue]
```

I understand how to do this as following:

```
http://demo-name.com/l/[shortvalue]
```

using a basic rewrite rule, however, I am unsure of how to do this without the prefix of the `l`.

I will also need to be able to go to

```
http://demo-name.com/file.php
```

to run certain files, so this needs to be possible.

If it is also possible, I would like to be able to have a

```
http://demo-name.com/[shortvalue]?key=val&key2=val2
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

query string at the end of my URL's, so if `[QSA]` is possible as well, that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

You can test if a file is a directory (`-d`) or a file (`-f`) in a `RewriteCond`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ index.php?shorturl=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This rule will rewrite any "shortvalue" without slashes or dots to `index.php?shorturl=shortvalue`.